# Should I publish the nuspec file in a repository?

Tags: nuget, nuget-spec

When creating an open source library on GitHub or another public website, should I publish the .nuspec file that describes the corresponding NuGet package?

I've done this a couple of times (since no API key or other sensitive information is included in the .nuspec file) in order to allow myself to easily publish subsequent versions without keeping private file, and to allow other people to fork it and add their own descriptions easily. However, the developers of many top packages don't seem to publish .nuspec files in their repositories (sometimes they publish NuGet.exe along with a .targets file, and so on), so I'm thinking that maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package authoring should be considered part of the source code since it is a required asset to build the fully usable output.

Some projects use special msbuild-based tooling to create the nuspec file during the build so it seems like there is none in the repository. the new "SDK-based" projects (e.g. .NET Standard libraries) have integrated nuget tooling to be able to create a nupkg file from the csproj without the need to create a nuspec file. This tooling is also being adopted by some popular packages (e.g. Newtonsoft.Json).